Terraform fetch provider version
I am using terraform azure provider to deploy our infrastructure on Azure
I am using the azurerm provider
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 1.3.0"
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      version = "4.12.0"
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
    }
  }
  backend "azurerm" {}
}

I'd like now to use the azurerm version (4.12.0) and add it to a local variable
locals {
  tags = merge(data.azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.tags, {
      azRmVersion : "4.12.0"
   })
}

I don't want to duplicate the version in my terraform code but instead I would like to have a variable or to fetch the provider version in order to use it as value of my azRmVersion  tag.
I understand that we cannot use variables in the terraform.required_providers.azurerm.version, is there another way that I can achieve my goal?
Why I want to do this?
While ago, I upgraded the provider to 3.111.0 and there were no issues (just because not all the resources had modifications).
After 6 months I've changed something in a very old resource and it was broken and I couldn't understand why. I spent hours investigating.
So just upgrading the provider, the issue was automatically solved. It was just a bug in the specific provider version that didn't show up during the provider upgrade since the specific resource had no modification.
So my idea is to add the provider version as a tag so whenever I want to test the new provider in dev, all my resources will have a modification.
In this way I am sure that all the resources will be tested against the new provider version.
Usually tags are harmless.
Maybe there is a better way, I am open to suggestions
Thank you

You cannot directly use variables or local values in the required_providers block to define the provider version. However, you can achieve your goal of avoiding duplication by using a combination of local variables and comments to maintain clarity in your code. While you cannot dynamically fetch the provider version directly, you can define it in a local variable and use that variable in your tags

While I can understand why it might seem useful to track in the remote system which version of the provider created each object, I would suggest that you don't do that because it means every time you upgrade the provider you'll be confronted with a huge diff that updates the tags on many resource instances, which will then make it harder to find whatever meaningful changes might appear as the result of a provider upgrade.

Terraform itself already keeps track of which provider versions it is using in its own records -- it tracks the selected provider version in the dependency lock file and the provider's schema version for each resource instance in state snapshots -- so duplicating that information into the remote API isn't really necessary.

@MartinAtkins Thanks for your input, that is exaclty what I wanted to achieve. It happened that I've upgraded the providerer to 3.111.0 and there were no issues (just because not all the resources had modifications). After 6 months I've changed something  in a resources and it was broken and I couldn't understand why. So just upgrading the provider it was automatically solved. So my idea is to add the provider version as a tag so whenever I want to test the new provider in dev I am sure that it won't have any impact. Usually tags are harmless. Any better Idea?

You cannot directly use variables or local values in the required_providers block to define the provider version. However, you can achieve your goal of avoiding duplication by using a combination of local variables. While you cannot dynamically fetch the provider version directly, you can define it in a local variable and use that variable in your tags.
Here is the updated code to fetch the tag from the version and add the same tag to a new resource group.
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 1.3.0"
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      version = "4.12.0"  # Specify the provider version
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}  # Add the features block here
  subscription_id = "09a9"
}

locals {
  azurerm_version = "4.12.0"  # Define the provider version here
  tags = merge({
    azRmVersion = local.azurerm_version
  })
}

# Create a new resource group using the tags
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "venkat-resources"
  location = "West Europe"
  tags = local.tags
}

terraform apply

After running the code, the new resource group has been created with a tag named: azRmVersion: 4.12.0.


Thank you, I already tried this solution, but it happened that I've updated the required_version but not the local variable, this is why I was looking for a solution to have them both in sync

To ensure synchronization between the provider version and the tag value, you can adopt a more automated approach by externalizing the provider version into a centralized file or environment variable. However, Terraform itself doesn't provide a native way to fetch the version from the required_providers block dynamically.
You can use a file, such as versions.tfvars, to define the version. When you update the provider version in versions.tfvars, it will automatically reflect in both the required_providers block and the resource tags

I hope this helps to resolve your issue.
